# Unit-length 2D curve segment with maximal width along all directions

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $C$ be a finite-length, continuous 2D curve segment.

Given a 2D direction $d$, let the *width* of $C$ along $d$ be the length of the projection of $C$ on $d$.  Or, equivalently, consider two parallel lines orthogonal to $d$: the width is the distance between the two farthest lines that both intersect $C$.

For a given curve segment $C$, let $m$ be the minimum value of the width of $C$ along all directions.  For example, if $C$ is a straight segment, $m = 0$ because its width along the orthogonal direction is 0.  If $C$ is a circumference, $m$ is its diameter.

[Example sketches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2rgZ.png)

I am interested in finding the curve $C$ with length 1 and the maximum possible value of $m$.

If we limit the search to closed curves, for symmetry the solution should be a circle with radius $\frac{1}{2\pi}$; then $m = \frac{1}{\pi}$.

If we allow $C$ to be an open curve then I feel that $m$ should increase, but I don't know where to look for the answer.  My guess is that $C$ should be symmetric wrt the perpendicular bisector of the straight segment joining the two endpoints. I also suspect that its width should be the same regardless on $d$, and that convex hulls may be somewhat related.